# Itext 7 throwing null pointer exception at license key validator

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

I am very new in itext and i am using version 7.1.4 and obtained a trial license key version 3.0.0 and typography version 2.0.2 .

```
public ByteArrayInputStream pdfReport()
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException, DocumentException, SurveyException {

    LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("E:/licence-key.xml");

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument, pagesize);
       /***************Some Codes***************/
        layoutDocument.close();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

This above method is called in my controller class. At first if I hit the request the pdf file is generated but in second request it shows the "406 not acceptable".The error is shown below:

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.itextpdf.licensekey.validators.LicenseKey7Validator.updateProductsOnLoad(LicenseKey7Validator.java:437) ~[itext-licensekey-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.licensekey.validators.LicenseKey7Validator.LoadLicense(LicenseKey7Validator.java:121) ~[itext-licensekey-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey.loadLicenseFileInternal(LicenseKey.java:182) ~[itext-licensekey-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LicenseKey.java:69) ~[itext-licensekey-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LicenseKey.java:94) ~[itext-licensekey-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.survey.application.pdfGenerator.PdfReportGenerator.pdfReport(PdfReportGenerator.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
at com.survey.application.controller.PdfController.generateReport(PdfController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
```

I am getting confused, howcome at first request it generates but in second,third and so on it throws the exception. Is it the way of loading the license key file . Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add LicenseKey7Validator class?

Comment: That is not the class I created. The  LicenseKey7Validator class is the Superclass of itextpdf http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/licensekey/changes-3.0.1-3.0.2/changes/com.itextpdf.licensekey.validators.LicenseKey7Validator.html

Comment: *"At first if I hit the request the pdf file is generated but in second request it shows the "406 not acceptable"."* - you should probably load the license only once instead of loading and re-loading it again and again.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Now it is solved.